# How to implement soft (logical) delete with MongoDB and Spring?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have Spring web app with MongoDB. Currently I always permanently delete data from database.

```
@Repository
public class SessionRepository extends CrudRepository implements SessionService {
  ...
  @Override
  public void insert(Session session) {
    saveRoom(session);
    getTemplate().insert(session);
  }

  @Override
  public void delete(Session session) {
    getTemplate().remove(session);
  }
  ...    
}
```

What would be a good way to change this into soft delete?

----------------- edit 1 -------------------

I understand the logic now what I should do, thanks Sarath Nair. But I am unsure how to implement this in Spring. I have a Session object:

```
@Document(collection = "session")
public class Session {

  @Id
  private String id;
  private Date startDate;
  private Date endDate;
//I just put this here
  private boolean deleted = false;

  public boolean isDeleted() {
    return deleted;
  }

  public void setDeleted(boolean deleted) {
    this.deleted = deleted;
  }

  ...
}
```

I want the field `boolean isDeleted` to be present in the database but I don't wan't to send that piece of information out with a web service.
`@Transient` is no good because then the field won't show up in database nor in the HTTP response. Right now I am sending `deleted: false` in my HTTP response.

How should I edit my Session class?

Comment: Found solution. Since Spring uses Jackson internally @JsonIgnore makes fields not appear in responses

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have an additional field called `is_deleted` in collection. Insert `is_deleted` as `false` for new documents. When you are deleting just update this value to `true` for that document. Whenever you need to read documents from collection, pass `is_deleted : false` for the collection.

Comment: and how do you use functionality like `@Where(is_deleted=true)` for mongo documents. because it is pretty convenient to have all "deleted" items not selected during a query right away

Answer (score 2):

Solution with "isDeleted" field will not work because @DbRef still retrieves the "isDeleted" records, I am playing around this problem too.

For your second question, you can use custom SpringHttpMessageConverters with GSON to hide "isDeleted" field.

Comment: I used @JsonIgnore for the "isDeleted" field since Spring uses Jackson internally. Now the field won't appear in HTTP response.

Comment: @potato300 I use GSon, so I cannot use @ JsonIgnore but I can find alternative for @ JsonIgnore, thank you!