# Soft Delete Procedure in MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

We are going to develop multi tenant based project, based on Java Spring Boot at backend and MongoDb as a database.

I want to ask that is there any procedure to make soft delete other than insert a attribute true/false or 0/1 ?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a soft delete?

Comment: by convention, you usually have boolean (true / false) property `isDeleted` in each document. After, when you do search (e.g. GET all docs), you search with the following condition `db.collectionName.find({ isDeleted: false })`. Same applies for other CRUD operations. Check the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33934245/how-to-implement-soft-logical-delete-with-mongodb-and-spring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to delete or use an attribute as a `isDeleted` or similar name. You have to move deleted documents to another collection namely `deletedCollections` and hard delete the current document from the current collection. This methodology can be useful to manage these unwanted or deleted data for current collection.

1. First create a another collection may be in another server or file system named as deletedCollection
2. First insert the document to this collection to be deleted
3. Then delete the current document from current collection

This way is useful to reach the deleted or archived data in another time.